# How to match title case sentences with prepositions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to extract title case sentences from documents using regex.
I want my regex to match the sentence when the prepositions are both capitalized and when not.

E.g. I want it to match:

> The Art of War
>
> The Art Of War

I've tried using several regex expressions on Reddit comments but I can never get the right sentence as I pick up many false positives.

I tried this regex in Python:

```py
import regex
pattern = regex.compile(r"\b(?<!^)(?<=[A-Z]\w*\s?)(a(?:nd?)?|the|to|[io]n|from|with|of|for)(?!$)(?!\s?[a-z])\b|\b([A-Z]\w*)")
reddit_comment= "Honestly 'The Art of War' should be required reading in schools (outside of China), it has so much wisdom packed into it that is so sorely lacking in our current education system."
pattern.findall(reddit_comment)
```

I expected it to just retrieve "The Art of War" but instead I get:

```py
[('', 'Honestly'),
 ('', 'The'),
 ('', 'Art'),
 ('of', ''),
 ('', 'War'),
 ('', 'China')]
```

Comment: Try `r'\b(?!^)[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+(?:a(?:nd?)?|the|to|[io]n|from|with|of|for|[A-Z]\w*))+\b'`

Comment: thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew, it works!! if you have time, I would appreciate if you could explain what you did there, otherwise, thanks anyway!

Comment: Let me post the answer, just a couple of minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'\b(?!^)[A-Z]\w*(?:\s+(?:a(?:nd?)?|the|to|[io]n|from|with|of|for|[A-Z]\w*))+\b'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FFcAPB/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!^)` - a negative lookahead: no start of string position at this place
- `[A-Z]` - an uppercase letter
- `\w*`  - 0+ letters, digits or `_`s
- `(?:\s+(?:a(?:nd?)?|the|to|[io]n|from|with|of|for|[A-Z]\w*))+` - zero or more repetitions of the patterns inside a non-capturing group:

  - `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
  - `(?:a(?:nd?)?|the|to|[io]n|from|with|of|for|[A-Z]\w*)` - any of

    - `a(?:nd?)?` - `a`, `an`, `and`
    - `|the|to|` - or `the` or `to` or
    - `[io]n` - `in` or `on`
    - `|from|with|of|for|` - or `from` or `with` or `of` or `for`
    - `[A-Z]\w*` - an uppercase letter and  0+ letters, digits or `_`s
- `\b` - a word boundary

Answer (score 0):

I think its not feasible matching it by Regex.

You can use a package called NLTK which [`tokenizes`](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html) and gets the [`Parts of Speech (POS)`](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) from those tokenized words and returns a list of tuple which you run your custom business logic on.

```
import nltk

str = r"Honestly 'The Art of War' should be required reading in schools (outside of China), it has so much wisdom packed into it that is so sorely lacking in our current education system."

tagged_text = nltk.word_tokenize(str)

pos_tags = nltk.pos_tag(tagged_text)

print (pos_tags)
```

Outputting:

```
[
    ('Honestly', 'RB'), 
    ("'The", 'POS'), 
    ('Art', 'NNP'), 
    ('of', 'IN'), 
    ('War', 'NNP'), 
    ("'", 'POS'), 
    ('should', 'MD'), 
    ('be', 'VB'), 
    ('required', 'VBN'), 
    ('reading', 'NN'),
    ('in', 'IN'),
    ('schools', 'NNS'), 
    ('(', '('), 
    ('outside', 'IN'), 
    ('of', 'IN'), 
    ('China', 'NNP'), 
    (')', ')'), 
    (',', ','), 
    ('it', 'PRP'), 
    ('has', 'VBZ'), 
    ('so', 'RB'), 
    ('much', 'JJ'), 
    ('wisdom', 'NN'), 
    ('packed', 'VBD'), 
    ('into', 'IN'), 
    ('it', 'PRP'), 
    ('that', 'WDT'), 
    ('is', 'VBZ'), 
    ('so', 'RB'), 
    ('sorely', 'RB'), 
    ('lacking', 'VBG'), 
    ('in', 'IN'), 
    ('our', 'PRP$'), 
    ('current', 'JJ'), 
    ('education', 'NN'), 
    ('system', 'NN'), 
    ('.', '.')
]
```

Here `'IN'` means preposition.